# If and A and B are separated and C is a connected subset of $A\cup B$, then either $C\subset A$ or $C\subset B$.

Tags: proof-verification

> If and A and B are separated and C is a connected subset of $A\cup B$, then either $C\subset A$ or $C\subset B$.

Proof: Suppose by contradiction that it's $\underline{not}$ the case that either $C\subset A$ or $C\subset B$, then by demorgan's law $C\not\subset A$ and $C\not\subset B$. If A and B are separated meaning that $\overline{A}\cap B=\varnothing=A\cap\overline{B}$ and $C\subset A\cup B$, but then $C\subset A$ or $C\subset B$.  Hence, by contradiction $C\subset A$ or $C\subset B$.

---

I feel like its not enough. Thank you.

Comment: How do you define separated? Does it just mean that the intersection is empty?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No was missing that, $\overline{A}\cap B=\varnothing=A\cap \overline{B}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"but then $C \subset A$ or $C \subset B$" assumes what you are trying to prove.

If neither $C \subset A$ nor $C \subset B$, then $C = (C \cap A) \cup (C \cap B)$ with both  $C \cap A \neq \varnothing$ and $C \cap B \neq \varnothing$.  But the separation of $A$ and $B$ separates these two pieces of $C$.  Therefore, $C$ is not connected.

Comment: I knew I was missing something.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

But $A \cap B$ empty; $C \subset A \cup B$; do NOT necessarily imply that one of $C \subset A$ or $C \subset B$ has to hold. So your line of reasoning isn't correct there.

Suppose $C$ intersects both $A$ and $B$. Then $C$ connected implies that $C \cap A$ is connected to $C \cap B$. This contradicts $A$ and $B$ being separated.

Comment: Connected does not necessarily mean path connected.

Comment: Yes indeed. Editting

Comment: The idea is that connectedness defines an equivalence class; a set is connected if every member is in the same such equivalence class, and $A$ and $B$ are separated if no member of $A$ is in the same such equivalence class as any member of $B$.